# How to align navbar items to the top?

Tags: css

I created a navbar with an ordered list, I want to position these list items to against the top of the navbar, I tried `margin-top: 0` but that didn't work.

Could anyone please help?

```css
#widgets:hover #widgetssub {
  display: block;
}

#widgetssub {
  display: none;
}

#kabobs:hover #kabobssub {
  display: block;
}

#kabobssub {
  display: none;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 40px;
  ;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 0px
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="menu">
    <ol>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Home</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">About</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item" id="widgets">
        <a href="#0">Widgets</a>
        <ol class="sub-menu" id="widgetssub">
          <li class="sub-item"><a href="#0">Big Widgets</a></li>
          <li class="sub-item"><a href="#0">Bigger Widgets</a></li>
          <li class="sub-item"><a href="#0">Huge Widgets</a></li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item" id="kabobs">
        <a href="#0">Kabobs</a>
        <ol class="sub-menu" id="kabobssub">
          <li class="sub-item"><a href="#0">Shishkabobs</a></li>
          <li class="sub-item"><a href="#0">BBQ kabobs</a></li>
          <li class="sub-item"><a href="#0">Summer kabobs</a></li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Contact</a></li>
    </ol>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `margin: 0` and possibly `padding: 0` (depending on what you need) to the `ol` element:

```css
#widgets:hover #widgetssub{
  display: block;
}
#widgetssub{
  display: none;
}

#kabobs:hover #kabobssub{
  display: block;
}
#kabobssub{
  display: none;
}
ol{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu-item{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 40px;;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 0px

}
.menu{
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
    <nav class="menu">
    <ol>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">About</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item" id="widgets">
      <a href="#0">Widgets</a>
      <ol class="sub-menu" id="widgetssub">
        <li class="sub-item"><a href="#0">Big Widgets</a></li>
        <li class="sub-item"><a href="#0">Bigger Widgets</a></li>
        <li class="sub-item"><a href="#0">Huge Widgets</a></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item" id="kabobs">
      <a href="#0">Kabobs</a>
      <ol class="sub-menu" id="kabobssub">
        <li class="sub-item"><a href="#0">Shishkabobs</a></li>
        <li class="sub-item"><a href="#0">BBQ kabobs</a></li>
        <li class="sub-item"><a href="#0">Summer kabobs</a></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Contact</a></li>
    </ol>
    </nav>
```

Comment: if this answer help you, you should accept this answer @Chenius

Comment: @Zuber I did, I checked the tick, it is green

Comment: @Chenius Yes i have checked, Its just for helping the answerer so that they can gain some reputation :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `margin` of `ol`. just add this `css`

```
.menu ol {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin: 0;` to the `<ol>` tag

```css
 #widgets:hover #widgetssub{
  display: block;
}
#widgetssub{
  display: none;
}

#kabobs:hover #kabobssub{
  display: block;
}
#kabobssub{
  display: none;
}
ol{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu-item{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 40px;;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 0px

}
.menu{
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <nav class="menu">
    <ol>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">About</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item" id="widgets">
      <a href="#0">Widgets</a>
      <ol class="sub-menu" id="widgetssub">
        <li class="sub-item"><a href="#0">Big Widgets</a></li>
        <li class="sub-item"><a href="#0">Bigger Widgets</a></li>
        <li class="sub-item"><a href="#0">Huge Widgets</a></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item" id="kabobs">
      <a href="#0">Kabobs</a>
      <ol class="sub-menu" id="kabobssub">
        <li class="sub-item"><a href="#0">Shishkabobs</a></li>
        <li class="sub-item"><a href="#0">BBQ kabobs</a></li>
        <li class="sub-item"><a href="#0">Summer kabobs</a></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Contact</a></li>
    </ol>
    </nav>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the same problem for my website navbar.

When the element locates at low point, use margin-top=0, padding-top=0 will let you move the element to top of its own container. But in many cases like my case, this tip does not help because by default alignment it already starts low position.

To push the element upwards within its parents' container, have to use margin-top= -40px; for my navbar

Below code is the ul when I forced its margin top and padding top of zeros (Bootstrap 4 syntax mt-0, pt-0; or equivalently CSS syntax style="margin-top: 0px; padding-top:0px").

But this way did not move the ul upwards from its default alignment, i.e. at mid height of the navbar. I want to have the ul the same height level as the top edge of the yellow logo block

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm bg-primary fixed-top"> 
        <div class="container"> 
            <div class="mb-2 mr-sm-2"><a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="#"><div style="background-color: yellow;width: 60px; height: 60px;"> </div></a></div> <!--highlight brand/logo, auto style/size logo image -->
            <div class="mb-2 mr-sm-2 collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar"> 
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-0 pt-0" style="margin-top: 0px; padding-top:0px">
                    <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <h5>Home</h5></a></li>
                </ul>       
            </div> <!-- END collapsable items-->                                   
        </div>  
    </nav> <!-- END navbar-->
```

Below code is when margin-top=-40px is applied to the ul. Now the ul is the same  level with the top edge of the yellow logo block

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm bg-primary fixed-top"> 
        <div class="container"> 
            <div class="mb-2 mr-sm-2"><a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="#"><div style="background-color: yellow;width: 60px; height: 60px;"> </div></a></div> <!--highlight brand/logo, auto style/size logo image -->
            <div class="mb-2 mr-sm-2 collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar"> 
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" style="margin-top: -40px">
                    <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <h5>Home</h5></a></li>
                </ul>       
            </div> <!-- END collapsable items-->                                   
        </div>  
    </nav> <!-- END navbar-->
```